# Redundancy in class based generic views

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have two simple class based generic views which simply render a template. Since they look almost the same and I want to stay dry I wanted to ask you, what would be the smartest and best way to implement this right now:

First View

```
class Foo(TemplateView):
  template_name = "Foo.html"

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    user = User.objects.get(username = self.request.user)
    context = super(Foo, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['foo_objs'] = Foo.objects.filter(user = user.id)
    return context

class Bar(TemplateView):
  template_name = "bar.html"

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    user = User.objects.get(username = self.request.user)
    context = super(Bar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['bar_objs'] = Bar.objects.filter(user = user.id)
    return context
```

Comment: Your user query is a) wrong and b) unnecessary. `self.request.user` is already a User instance, not a username, so there is simply no need to query User again.

Comment: @DanielRoseman have a model called User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create intermediate view class with additional attribute `model` and then inherit your views from it:

```
class ModelListTemplateView(TemplateView):

    model = None

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [self.model._meta.model_name + '.html']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ModelListTemplateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
        context['%s_objs' % self.model._meta.model_name] = \
                                    self.model.objects.filter(user=user.id)
        return context


class FooView(ModelListTemplateView):
    model = Foo

class BarView(ModelListTemplateView):
    model = Bar
```